# How to return all of the data in a COLORREF to the caller in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I'm trying to write a `.dll` and then call this `.dll` in C#. I followed this article:

https://blog.quickbird.uk/calling-c-from-net-core-759563bab75d

Now, I have the problem of how to return all of the data in a `COLORREF` to the caller in C#, and then to be able to distinguish the values.

This is the source from the `.dll`:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) COLORREF __stdcall getColor(int X, int Y) {
        HDC _hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        COLORREF _result = 0;
        if (_hdc)
        {
            _result = GetPixel(_hdc, X, Y);
        /*  int _red = GetRValue(_result);
            int _green = GetGValue(_result);
            int _blue = GetBValue(_result);   */
            ReleaseDC(NULL, _hdc);
            return _result;
        }
        return _result;
    }
}
```

And here are some parts from the C# source:

```cs
public partial class Main_Window : Form
{
    [DllImport(@"test.dll", EntryPoint = "getColor", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern UInt32 getColor(int X, int Y);

    private void ColB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UInt32 result = getColor(500, 500);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(result)); //<--- just to show what pops up.
        //ColB.BackColor = result; //<--- that didnt work.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COLORREF` is just an alias for `DWORD`, which is indeed `UInt32` in C#. So, your code looks fine, as far as calling your `getColor()` function in C#.  Though, I would suggest making the function return `CLR_INVALID` (`0xFFFFFFFF`) on failure rather than returning 0 (Black), especially since `GetPixel()` returns `CLR_INVALID` on failure, eg:

```cpp
COLORREF __stdcall getColor(int X, int Y) {
    COLORREF _result = CLR_INVALID;
    HDC _hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    if (_hdc)
    {
        _result = GetPixel(_hdc, X, Y);
        ReleaseDC(NULL, _hdc);
    }
    return _result;
}
```

That being said, the [`BackColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor?view=netcore-3.1) property of a control expects a [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netcore-3.1), not a `UInt32`.  You can get a `Color` from a `COLORREF` by using one of the [`Color.FromArgb()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netcore-3.1) methods, eg:

```cs
UInt32 result = getColor(500, 500);
if (result != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
    int red = (int) (byte) (result & 0xFF);
    int green = (int) (byte) ((result >> 8) & 0xFF);
    int blue = (int) (byte) ((result >> 16) & 0xFF);
    ColB.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
}
```

Or, the [`System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromWin32()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromwin32?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_ColorTranslator_FromWin32_System_Int32_) method:

```cs
UInt32 result = getColor(500, 500);
if (result != 0xFFFFFFFF) {
    ColB.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromWin32( (int) result );
}
```